# How To make this TextBox in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to acchive the textbox which will look like this and this is disable user can't change content in it.

[image]

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextField(
  readOnly: true,
  controller: TextEditingController()..text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the \nprinting and typesetting industry",
  minLines: 3,
  maxLines: 3,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
       labelText: "Explaination",
       labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500), 
       border: OutlineInputBorder()
  ),
),
```